# How normalize the tensor signal in tensorflow 1.x

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, neural-network

I have a tensor signal X (a signal which represent the output of neural network). I want to normalize it as the following line written in matlab:

```
Y = X*sqrt(length(X))/norm(X);
```

following Tf1 guide, I did it as below:

```
Y =  tf.math.divide(tf.math.multiply(X , tf.math.sqrt(tf.shape(X))),tf.norm(X))
```

But I get an error, .. Is there another method I can do that operation or correct my above command.

thank you

Comment: It's pretty hard to debug what's happening here without more context... I can identify 2 possible problems: (1) `tf.shape(X)` returns a tuple, perhaps you want the length of the first dimension, as in `tf.shape(X)[0]`? (2) `tf.norm(X)` returns a scalar, did you mean to use `keepdims=True`? Also, I would suggest using simple python operators instead of tf.math, to make your code more elegant (i.e., `Y = (X * (tf.shape(X)[0]**2)) / tf.norm(X)`- TF supports this.

Comment: OK, when using  Y = (X * (tf.shape(X)[0]**2)) / tf.norm(X)   I got this error TypeError: Input 'y' of 'Mul' Op has type int32 that does not match type float32 of argument 'x'.

Comment: I have a question, in matlab function you are performing square root, but in tensorflow you are squaring it, why ?

Comment: @KnowledgeGainer In the question, I am performing square root, I have just tried to use command provided by pp1 to seen if it will work

Comment: try to cast the output after multiplication like= `(tf.cast( (X * (tf.shape(X)[0]**2)), tf.float32))/tf.norm(X)`

Comment: @KnowledgeGainer I get the same error which is : TypeError: Input 'y' of 'Mul' Op has type int32 that does not match type float32 of argument 'x'.

Comment: You need to cast the shape to float32, i.e., `tf.cast(tf.shape(X)[0], tf.float32)`, not the multiplication.

Comment: @pp1 Yes, that worked, could you write that as an answer to close the question, and modify the square **2  into square root.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per our discussion, TensorFlow is sensitive to the data types that are used in the math operators. The solution to this problem is to use the first dimension of the data's shape, i.e., `tf.shape(X)[0]`, and then cast it to `tf.float32` type, since the output of your neural network is in that type as well.

The full formula is as follows:

```
Y = (X * tf.sqrt(tf.cast(tf.shape(X)[0], dtype=tf.float32))) / tf.norm(X)
```

Comment: When I use this method to get the square root, I get an error, so I used the following way:  Y = X* tf.cast(tf.sqrt(tf.cast(tf.shape(X)[0], tf.float32)), tf.float32)/tf.norm(X)

Comment: I fixed the solution. Thanks.